# Partial function application in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, partial-application

I am having trouble with syntax for partial function application.  The following code works fine, and it outputs: `two-three-four`

```
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.*

inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachFrom(beg:Int, act:(T)->Unit) {
  var i=0;  if (beg>=0) for (e in this) if (i++ >= beg) act(e)
}    // sample function I am testing; please don't change this!

fun main(a:Array<String>) {
  val l = listOf("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four")
  fun test() = buildSequence { l.forEachFrom(2) { yield(it) } }.joinToString("-")
  println(test())
}
```

I'd like to encapsulate my `test()`, so it is called as:
`test(l.forEachFrom(2))`  However, I can't seem to get the types/syntax right. 
 **How would I re-write the `test()` function definition to make this possible?**

Comment: But your `act` returns `Unit`, how could that `yield` gather something?

Comment: The biggest problem in your case that prevents me from arriving at an easy solution is that Kotlin coroutines can do suspend calls only from higher-order functions that are inlined, so you cannot just make a partially applied function by writing a lambda that works with the last argument and pass `{ yield(it) }` there: the compiler needs the place where you pass it to be an inline function.

Comment: @hotkey Inline could be ok for these test procedures, but I'm still not sure what that syntax would look like.  I tried, but I think I'm still not getting the types right.  Could you show me what the syntax would look like if everything were inlined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. If you give more details we can provide a better answer. That said, the following code will hopefully point you in the right direction.

```
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.*

inline fun <T,S> Iterable<T>.mapFrom(beg:Int, act:(T)->S) =
    drop(beg).map {act(it)}

fun main(a:Array<String>) {
    val l = listOf("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four")
    fun <T> test(values: List<T>) = values.joinToString("-")
    println(test(l.mapFrom(2) {it}))
}
```

`forEachFrom` was not really being used as a `forEach`, but as a `map`. This was the main issue, as you were using `yield` to output the results instead of just returning the results. If `forEachFrom` was also going to be used for its side-effects, it can still be used for that purpose.

Also, there was no reason for `test` to take a function as a parameter instead of just accepting the output of that function as its parameter. The `buildSequence` call was also redundant as you immediately call `joinToString` which is terminal and forces eager computation of the function inside `buildSequence`.